# How can I enable mod_rewrite logs?

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm having trouble with my .htaccess redirects, and I want to enable logs on the the mod_rewrite module so I can figure out what's going on. The trouble is, httpd.conf doesn't seem to exist anymore in 12.10, and all the guides I can find for enabling logs (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286004/hidden-features-of-mod-rewrite)) suggest editing httpd.conf. How can I enable mod_rewrite logs?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search for "mod_rewrite logging" gave me [this URL which answers your question](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/logging.html).

```
RewriteLog /home/path/to/desired/log/file.txt
RewriteLogLevel 5
```

For more information on how to configure Apache on Ubuntu, see [Ubuntu Server Guide - HTTPD](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html) for details.

Comment: That link suggests modifying httpd.conf, which as I say in the question, doesn't seem to exist in 12.10. See this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077488

Comment: I know I have to put that in "the config file," but what exactly is that file called, and where is it located? That's the whole point of my question. Recent versions of Apache don't allow you to put this in .htaccess.

Comment: I didn't have to enable my site--I just installed apache the normal way on ubuntu. I haven't actually edited any config files, so I still don't know what config file you mean. `/etc/apache2/sites-available` contains two files: `default` and `default-ssl`.